# How to solve problem with transparent area in PNG image?

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I use Paint.Net in Windows to make mask png image from source png.

```
def mask (im):    
    newimdata = []
    transparent = (255, 255, 255, 0)
    black = (0,0,0)
    white = (255,255,255)   
    for color in im.getdata():       
        if color == transparent:
            newimdata.append(white)
        else:
            newimdata.append(black)
    newim = Image.new(im.mode,im.size)
    newim.putdata(newimdata)
    return newim

img = Image.open(thumb)
img = img.convert("RGBA")
mask(img).show()
```

The result is little weird.

Source png.

[image]

Mask png.

[image]

Left transparent rectangle I made in PaintNet: I clicked mouse, made transparent area.

Right transparent rectangle I made: I clicked mouse, made transparent area. After I clicked mouse once again and made transparent vertical figures on transparent rectangle.

I don't understand: Is it two transparent layers (right rectangle and vertical figures)?

How can I merge this to make mask as in left clean rectangle?

Comment: What are you hoping to do please?

Comment: @Mark Setchell , I want to make right rectangle clean white, without vertical figures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what you are trying to do, but want to show you how the 4 channels (RGBA) of your image look. R is on the left, then G, then B with A (alpha/transparency) on the right.

[image]

I guess you just want the rightmost (A) channel, so with PIL, that is:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open('....')
alpha = im.getchannel('A')
```

If you want all the channels, use:

```
R, G, B, A = im.split()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I searched for.